# How do I add a subtotal to a filtered RDLC tablix?

Tags: report, rdlc

I have created a tablix which is filtered by dataset field which is not presented in tablix itself. Next I added a sum in footer row :

```
=Strings.FormatNumber(Sum(CDec(Fields!BillHours.Value)), 2)
```

However the produced sum is of all dataset BillHours and not filtered one. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filter condition you could try the following,
=Strings.FormatNumber(Sum(IIF(FilterCondition, CDec(Fields!BillHours.Value)), 0), 2)

How are you doing the filtering?